# Change content of div based on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onclick

simply enough, I want to change the class of a div via jQuery, with a click on an `<a>` element, depending on matching IDs
You should know I'm not experienced in JavaScript/jQuery and my code is googled together.

The idea is a list of months and a default content. If you click on a month it displays month-specific content and hides the default content.

I made a codepen with my situation: http://codepen.io/garrthes/pen/oXqzdL

I ripped off this code, but it won't work in my case: http://codepen.io/JoshBlackwood/pen/yoLBJ (Big thanks to you, JoshBlackwood!)

I don't know if this is relevant, but I want to run this inside of Wordpress. The jQuery library is loaded inside Wordpress.

I believe the error lies within the JS...

Thanks very much in advance!

HTML

```
    <div class="eventmobile">
<ul class="eevmonths">
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">12</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="eventtablet">
<ul class="eevmonths">
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Jan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Feb</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Mär</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Apr</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Mai</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Jun</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Jul</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Aug</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Sep</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Okt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Nov</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Dez</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="eventlarge">
<ul class="eevmonths">
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Januar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Februar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">März</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">April</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Mai</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Juni</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Juli</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">August</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">September</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Oktober</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">November</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eevcontent">Dezember</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="eevcontent">
<div class="eevdefault-text">Default Text</div>

<div class="eevcontent-jan eevhide">
<h3>Januar</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-feb eevhide">
<h3>Februar</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-mar eevhide">
<h3>März</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-apr eevhide">
<h3>April</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-mai eevhide">
<h3>Mai</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-jun eevhide">
<h3>Juni</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-jul eevhide">
<h3>Juli</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-aug eevhide">
<h3>August</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-sep eevhide">
<h3>September</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-okt eevhide">
<h3>Oktober</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-nov eevhide">
<h3>November</h3>
</div>
<div class="eevcontent-dez eevhide">
<h3>Dezember</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px){
  .eventtablet{
    display:none;
  }
  .eventlarge{
    display:none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1259px) and (min-width:451px){
  .eventmobile{
    display:none;
  }
  .eventlarge{
    display:none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1260px){
.eventmobile{
  display:none;
}
.eventtablet{
  display:none;
}
}

.eevhide {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

$('ul.eevmonths > a').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $id = $this.attr('sid'),
            $class = '.' + $('.eevcontent-' + $id).attr('class').replace('eevhide', '');
        $('.eevdefault-text').addClass('eevhide');
        $('.eevcontent-' + $id).removeClass('eevhide');
        $('div[class*=eevcontent]').not($class).addClass('eevhide');
    });
});
```

Comment: You should post your code in your question.  Many people won't click on an external link, and you haven't provided links anyway.  When you post your code here you keep the code with the discussion.  Who knows what may happen to an external link

Comment: Check out the toggleClass() function!

Comment: the first error that your code has, is that there isnt the Jquery library linked. Pleas fix this first.

Comment: Your jquery is a bit messy, can you explain what you wanna do in term of  html/jquery? For example: "I wanna take this div with this id and replace its class with this class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok dude, i figured out your question, and i made some change to the HTML/JQUERY because it was a complete mess. It should be simple to understand, but if you have any question, feel free to ask

https://jsfiddle.net/bpjk8174/3/

HTML

```
<div class="eventmobile">
<ul class="eevmonths">
    <li><a class="jan">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="feb">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="mar">3</a></li>
    <li><a class="apr">4</a></li>
    <li><a class="mai">5</a></li>
    <li><a class="jun">6</a></li>
    <li><a class="jul">7</a></li>
    <li><a class="aug">8</a></li>
    <li><a class="sep">9</a></li>
    <li><a class="okt">10</a></li>
    <li><a class="nov">11</a></li>
    <li><a class="dez">12</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="eventtablet">
<ul class="eevmonths">
    <li><a class="jan">Jan</a></li>
    <li><a class="feb">Feb</a></li>
    <li><a class="mar">Mär</a></li>
    <li><a class="apr">Apr</a></li>
    <li><a class="mai">Mai</a></li>
    <li><a class="jun">Jun</a></li>
    <li><a class="jul">Jul</a></li>
    <li><a class="aug">Aug</a></li>
    <li><a class="sep">Sep</a></li>
    <li><a class="okt">Okt</a></li>
    <li><a class="nov">Nov</a></li>
    <li><a class="dez">Dez</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="eventlarge">
<ul class="eevmonths">
    <li><a class="jan">Januar</a></li>
    <li><a class="feb">Februar</a></li>
    <li><a class="mar">März</a></li>
    <li><a class="apr">April</a></li>
    <li><a class="mai">Mai</a></li>
    <li><a class="jun">Juni</a></li>
    <li><a class="jul">Juli</a></li>
    <li><a class="aug">August</a></li>
    <li><a class="sep">September</a></li>
    <li><a class="okt">Oktober</a></li>
    <li><a class="nov">November</a></li>
    <li><a class="dez">Dezember</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="eevcontent">
    <div class="eevdefault-text">Default Text</div>

    <div class="eevcontent-jan eevhide">
    <h3>Januar</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-feb eevhide">
    <h3>Februar</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-mar eevhide">
    <h3>März</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-apr eevhide">
    <h3>April</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-mai eevhide">
    <h3>Mai</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-jun eevhide">
    <h3>Juni</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-jul eevhide">
    <h3>Juli</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-aug eevhide">
    <h3>August</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-sep eevhide">
    <h3>September</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-okt eevhide">
    <h3>Oktober</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-nov eevhide">
    <h3>November</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="eevcontent-dez eevhide">
    <h3>Dezember</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
    $('ul.eevmonths a').on('click', function () {
        $month = $(this).attr('class'),
        $('.eevcontent-'+$month).siblings().addClass('eevhide');
        $('.eevcontent-'+$month).removeClass('eevhide');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Woohoo! It works :)
Thanks a lot! Contact me if you happen to be somewhere near Austria, I owe you a beer (or a beverage of your choice! srsly!)